# Uploading local asset hangs and produces jQuery console error

Tags: assets, error-message, image, upload, jquery

So I have created an Assets field and am using it in one of my Entries. However, when I try to upload an image, it just keeps loading. I am getting the following console error:

[image: console error when trying to upload asset]

Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ralph! Would you mind posting an answer here for posterity if you figured it out, or accepting Brad's answer if it got you un-stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this support article to help debug failed uploads: https://craftcms.com/support/upload-troubleshooting